# How to build a profile using Activity data

Tags: wordpress, profile, activities

I need a logged in user to be able to add an activity but Civi keeps telling me "Profile search, view and edit are not supported for Profiles which include fields for more than one record type."
Here's what I did:
1.  Created a new activity type called "CEU"(Continuing Education Unit)
2.  Created a new Custom Data set called "CEU data" used for "Activities" and Type "CEU"
3.  Created a new Profile with Activity Date and the 6 CEU custom fields and it is used for "Standalone Form"

Civi does not give me the "Use Profile-Create Mode" like normal.
I also tried to add First Name, Last Name, and Email to the Profile but still got the same results.

Comment: Hey Gary - what CMS is this? I don't think civi out of box can do this. On Drupal you can use Webforms to let anon create Activities if tht is the goal

Comment: my bad...   CMS WP4.2.4 and Civi 4.6.4.   So I can't do an Activity Profile with WP?

Comment: If i am right, then it more a case that 'Activity Profile' can't be done with CiviCRM, but Drupal has a way around it, but also am wondering if somebody has found a generic solution, though this forum/SE doesn't offer much hope as i read it https://forum.civicrm.org/index.php?topic=34445.0

Answer (score 2):

Not out of the box, you could use CiviCRM hooks (hook_civicrm_postProcess) to create an activity on form submission.

You could also check [CiviVIP](http://civivip.com) they developed a WordPress [plugin](http://civivip.com) which does that (you will also need Gravity Forms), for the moment the plugin its only able to create contacts and activities, but they have plans for Event registration and Contributions.

Comment: PS: if you are interested in the WordPress plugin, I can make some tests, as I'm not quite sure if allows to expose custom activity fields. Or you can drop them a line.

Comment: I decided to use a Custom Set with Multiple Records.  This easily allows you to create a Profile for the user for data entry.  I like the Edit mode but the final save button gives you an error.  The final Save button is not really needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit of a workaround, but for simple forms where I wanted to avoid CMS-specific form plugins (or where I was embedding a form into another site), I used the following combination:

- [remoteform](https://github.com/progressivetech/net.ourpowerbase.remoteform/)
- [activityprofile](https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/activityprofile)

The activityprofile extension only works in combination with remoteform (it's a way to circumvent a CiviCRM limitation). If often use remoteform to embed forms within the same website, or a separate site.

Known limitation: for now, activityprofile will always create a new contact, i.e. potentially create duplicate contacts.

[image: screencast of remoteform and activityprofile]

Answer (score 1):

i think this can be done with Caldera and CiviCRM now