# Latest 'Note' field is not being used in the "Profiles - Admin Notification" email template

Tags: profile, message-templates, admin

Was wondering if anyone else has seen this problem and found a fix.  I was going to test on the Demo site, http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org, but I figured I wouldn't be able to receive the email to see if the problem exists there since I'm not an Admin.

The situation is that I'm leveraging the existing ***Note*** field for Contacts in a Contact Us profile used on our WordPress Frontend.  Basically option #1 indicated in the first paragraph of the answer for the following question:

[Creating a Contact Form in CiviCRM](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/8144/creating-a-contact-form-in-civicrm)

When the Admin receives the email from the Contact Us profile submission it seems to always parse in the first ***Note*** for the contact and not the last ***Note*** (which would have been what was submitted at the time).

Comment: It is possible to test  the sending of emails on the http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org. First set _Settings - Outbound Mail_ on redirect to database. Then you can find the email with _Mailings - Archived Mailings_ .

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using "Notes", consider creating an activity instead - and instead of using Profiles, use [Caldera Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/caldera-forms/) with [CiviCRM integration](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm) to create the Activity.

There are several advantages, including those I [mention here](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/a/25436/12), but also that you won't get the wrong "note", or pollute your notes data with information that's not really a note.

Answer (score 0):

I gather this is tricky in WP as there is not an easy solution that triggers the creation of an Activity, which imo is the logical way to do this in civicrm.

In this [answer](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/4809/how-to-build-a-profile-using-activity-data) they talk about CiviVIP and their [Gravity Forms integration][3] but of course there is a cost for that plugin.

Comment: You can do this with Caldera Forms - I left a separate answer with more details.